# how to Moniter cpu status using chef?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, cloud, ruby, chef

i try with java and ruby for moniter EC2 instance with aws sdk but not able to find any example how to moniter ec2 instacne with chef. can any one help to find example to moniter ec2 instance so we are validate which is the best option to moniter EC2 instance ?

monitoring like cpu-utilization disk-io,network-io

Comment: Chef is a configuration management and system integration framework, not a monitoring tool. You'd use Chef to inform your monitoring tools, not *as* a monitoring tool.

Comment: He should get a medal for the -5. It's a special occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use Chef to monitor system statistics?  There are any number of tools available (I prefer pnp4nagios for pretty graphs, and sysstat for detailed data collection) that are specifically designed for this sort of thing, why would you try and shoehorn monitoring into a configuration automation tool?